# What's the difference between "_" and "__" in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, syntax

I've read that `_` (underscore) is only used to tell that the variable/method/class is for the API use only and should not be used by other programmers.

What about `__` (double underscore)?

In this example `__block BOOL found = NO;`

From the Apple Docs about **Block Objects**.

Also, can anyone help me understand the concept of **pointer-to-pointers**? 
`**var`
I've read some answers about it but didn't really get it. When and how should I use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Single underscore is traditionally used for private API (methods and sometimes ivars). Their main purpose is to prevent name collisions.

`__block` is a keyword for the new blocks API. In general, double underscore keywords are for the compiler.

For pointers to pointers the `NSError` is a good example: When a method wants to return a new `NSError` object as part of its parameters (not return value), you need a pointer to a variable of type `NSError *`, so that you can assign it. With a simple pointer you could only access the object, but not (re-)assign it.